# What changes must a database provider do in the old entity framework provider (say EF5) to support the features of all the latest EF provider (EF6.x)?

Tags: database, entity-framework, visual-studio, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

What changes must a database provider (example oracle, mysql etc) do in the old entity framework provider (say EF5) to support the features of all the latest EF provider (EF6.x)?

Comment: Microsoft explained this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj730568 and here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rebuilding%20EF%20providers%20for%20EF6